# Modify a property of an object inside a method in its constructor in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, constructor

This is basically what I'm trying to do (I'm new to Javascript, so bear with me):

```
function Car(make)
{
    this.make = make;
    var noises = ["vroom", "woosh"];

    function addNoise()
    {
        noises.push("wham");
        this.noises = noises;
    }
    addNoise();
}

var myCar = new Car("honda");

console.log(myCar.noises[2]);
```

Now, I think the issue is that when I do `this.noises = noises;`, `this` isn't referring to `Car`, so when I try to do `console.log(myCar.noises[2]);` noises is undefined. In my actual code, the equivalent of `addNoise` runs asynchronously, so I have to be able to make `noises` a property inside that function.

---

Edit:

Yes, that other question covers a similar problem. This seems to work:

```
function Car(make)
{
    this.make = make;
    var noises = ["vroom", "woosh"];
    var self = this;

    function addNoise()
    {
        noises.push("wham");
        self.noises = noises;
    }
    addNoise();
}

var myCar = new Car("honda");

console.log(myCar.noises[2]);
```

Pretty simple solution!

Comment: You're right about `this`. I'm confused about how you organized your code, but to get around the immediate problem, you could do `addNoise.call(this);` instead of just `addNoise();` which sets the value of `this` as you want in `addNoise`

Comment: Or just omit the function definition and call at all, they're local only anyway.

Comment: I decided to close this as a duplicate since you mention *"In my actual code, the equivalent of addNoise runs asynchronously"*

Answer (score -1):

Best way to do this is to prototype the functions

```
functionon Car(make)
{
    this.make = make;
    this.noises = ["vroom", "woosh"];
    this.addNoise();
}

Car.prototype.addNoise = function() {
    this.noises.push("wham");
}

var myCar = new Car("honda");

console.log(myCar.noises[2]);
```